# Unreachable code detected

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, oledb

I'm getting a "Unreachable code detected" message in Visual Studio at the point con.close() in my code below. Can you spot what I've done wrong?

```
private int chek1(String insert)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=d:\\sdb.mdb");
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from sn where sn='" + insert + "\'", con);           
    con.Open();

    int po = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();           
    if (po > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    con.Close();    
}
```

Comment: Wow 2 more answers while I'm keying in mine.

Comment: Good answers all around, but I want to add that you could avoid the possibility of forgetting to close the connection if you used a `using`-statement instead. It gives you exception safety as well. You can return from within a using-statement body through the wonders of the compiler. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code could be like this:

```
private int check(string sn)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=d:\\sdb.mdb"))
    using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())          
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sn WHERE sn=?";
        command.Parameters.Add("@sn", sn));
        con.Open();               
        return ((int)com.ExecuteScalar() > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Drew Noakes: You just accidentally saw a moment between 2 edits

Answer (score 28):

The function exits when you return 1 or 0 (when you return *anything*, but 1 or 0 in *your* case); so there's no way that `con.Close()` can be called.

In the code you've posted, you're guaranteed to return, since you have a return statement in both branches of your if-statement.  If only one branch had a return statement,  `con.Close()` could still be reached.

But you shouldn't be using `Close` that way anyway -- you should be using `using` statements.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=d:\\sdb.mdb"))
using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from sn where sn='" + insert + "\'", con))
{
    con.Open();

    int po = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();           
    if (po > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

    // con.Close and con.Dispose will be called automatically at the end of the using block
}
```

Comment: thanks, so should I delete it, it is just waring not an error

Comment: @habbo95, no, don't just delete it, use the `using` statements as shown by Mark. This will automatically call `Dispose` on the connection and command, and disposing a connection closes it

Comment: @habbo95 well, it IS and error if it never gets closed.  "using" is idisposible, thus it closes/disposes of the connection

Answer (score 4):

You have an `if` / `else` above that will always trigger a `return`:

```
    if (po > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
```

So there is no possible way any code will execute after this snippet of code.

Answer (score 2):

```
 con.Close();
```

is unreachable. Either branch of the if statement returns so that line cannot be reached.

Answer (score 2):

you have a return before the end of your routine.  it will break out of that function before the Close() statement is called.  just move `con.Close()` before your `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (po > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
```

There's your problem. Either `po > 0` is true, in which case `1` is returned, either it isn't, in which case `0` is returned. No matter what, `con.Close();` will never get executed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to considering all the above answers, better consider using try..catch..finally and in finally, close the connection object. This will be better coding approach. You can improve your code like this.

```
private int chek1(String insert) {    
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=d:\\sdb.mdb");
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from sn where sn='" + insert + "\'", con);       
    try{    
        con.Open();

        int po = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();           
        if (po > 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work, but the use of "using" blocks, as in other answers is generally considered cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The reason has been answered, you should look at using the `using` statement. It will close your connection for you automatically.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=d:\\sdb.mdb"))
{
    using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from sn where sn='" + insert + "\'", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        int po = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();           
        if (po > 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `using` statements can be nested to decrease indent

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
int po = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();           
int result = 0;
if (po > 0) {
    result = 1;
}
con.Close();
return result;
```

in your case the `con.Close();` is not reached because the function returns earlier

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
private int chek1(String insert)
{
    OleDbConnection con = null;
    try {
    con = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=d:\\sdb.mdb");
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from sn where sn='" + insert + "\'", con);           
    con.Open();

    int po = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();           
    if (po > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    }
    finally {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unreachable because the method already return a value before its execute the con.Close() method.

Please Modify your code into:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=d:\\sdb.mdb"))
{
    using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from sn where sn='" + insert + "\'", con))
    {
        con.Open();

        int po = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();  

        return po > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```